# unable to perform operations on codesynthesis xml types

Tags: c++, xml, xsd

I have elements dateselection, blackscholes and volatility within my xml file, I would like to check the values of these, trying to print out content by using std::cout gives me build errors, also i would like to check if the elements exist within the xml file, for example if(blackscholes.exists()). does such functionality exist within code synthesis?

```
dateselection& date = i->dateselection();
const xsd::cxx::tree::date<char,simple_type>& end =  date.enddate();
const xsd::cxx::tree::sequence<bool, true>& black = i->blackscholes();
const xsd::cxx::tree::sequence<bool, true>& volatility = i->volatility();
```

Also can i convert the end date to a boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian type?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information: the schema file, the XML file, the error message. If the files are too big to be included in the question, try to show only the relevant parts of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking into the interface files (the hxx stubs generated) i found the the following types mapping to the xml library equivalent to strings and bool: ::xml_schema::string,  ::xml_schema::date,vanillaoption::blackscholes_type. The names may vary from schema to schema but using these to process and print out values worked for me (search for names with ::xml prefixes). To check for optional fields you must place elements within a "choice", the stubs will produce a function for each element called "present". You can use this to determine whether an element exists within a config file. For example

```
for(quantoptions::vanillaoption_iterator i (optionConfig->vanillaoption().begin()); i != optionConfig->vanillaoption().end(); ++i)
{
    dateselection& date = i->dateselection();
    ::xml_schema::string symbol = i->symbol();
    ::xml_schema::date &endDate =  date.enddate();
    if(i->blackscholes().present())
    {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```